# AsyncTask not working with arrays (android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want AsyncTask to download multiple files that i get as an array.
Using this code the AsyncTask only works once and ignore the rest of array.

```
private class DownloadFiles extends AsyncTask<String[], Integer, String> {
         @Override
         protected String doInBackground(String[]... sUrl) {

             for (int p = 0; p < sUrl.length; p++) {
                 for (int i=0;i<sUrl[p].length;i++) {
                     getFileToDown(sUrl[p][i]);
                 }
             }
```

For example i want to send more than array:

```
   downloadFiles.execute(databasesArray,imagesArray,etc);
```

Comment: Errr... `String ... urls` is *already* an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really need not declare `String[]` as generic parameter, but just a `String`:

```
AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

`doInBackground(String... sUrl)` by default expects an array of type parameter.

Also, `...` is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), and it represents an array of *optional* arguments.